# x \in U \Rightarrow f(x) \in U but converse is false

Tags: calculus

Hey I have a reasoning error and I really do not get where I am thinking wrong, so I would like to ask you if you could provide me some guidance.

I know $x \in U \Rightarrow f(x) \in f(U)$ but that the converse is false.

Now i want to prove that $f(\bigcap U_i) \subset \bigcap f(U_i)$.
So let $y \in f(\bigcap U_i) \Rightarrow  \exists x \in U_I: f(x)=y \Rightarrow \forall i \in I: x \in U_I$.

First I thought I would just use the definition of $f(U)$ in order to derive the first step and the second but now I think that I have violated $x \in U \not\Leftarrow f(x) \in f(U)$.But the proof is according to my manuskript true so I do not really get why I am allowed to claim that there is an x in the intersection of all U s.t f(x)=y.

I hope it is not too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You are fine.

If $y\in f(U)$ is is true that there exists $u\in U$ such that $y=f(u)$.

The problem is if $f(x)\in f(U)$... this does not imply that $x\in U$.

E.g. take $U=[0,\infty)$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. $f(U)=U$ and for any $y\in f(U)$ we have $f(\sqrt{y})=y$.

On the other hand $f(-1)=1\in U$ but $-1\not\in U$. There is however a $u\in U$ such that $f(u)=1$; e.g. $u=1$.

Comment: Thanks I got it so $x \in f(U) \Leftarrow f(x) \in f(U)$ would be true it f would be injective or?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your conflict is here:
$$f(x)=y \in f(U)\not \Rightarrow x\in U.$$
But is does say that there exist element in $U$ which has an image $y$. So your proof is fine.